# how to change the screenshot once your app goes live in iTunes?

Tags: app-store-connect

I have an app in iTunes that I need to change the Support URL since it has changed in the last 3 years.  The problem is the image is the wrong dimensions(it was grandfathered in to the newer system with old dimensions) and until I change the image I can't alter the URL.  But since the app is live I can't change the image.  Now what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the fields you want to change by setting up a new version of the app (making new app listing, uploading a new build). Apple only allows updates once the application has a new version.

Comment: It allows me to edit text, but return "1 or more errors present on the page".  I know it is the image.  But I can't change the image.